# How to make Selenium pick my .pac file?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, proxy, pac

I am using Foxyproxy in Firefox and whenever I want to switch to my sandbox environment I use a .pac file. Life is good.

But when I try to automate using a browser based testing utility like Selenium, I am not able to make it go through my Sandbox .pac proxy. How to achieve it ? I am using JUnit. Here is my sample code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteControlConfiguration;
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

public class TestCase1 extends SeleneseTestCase {

 Selenium selenium;
 public static final String MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MS = "60000";
 private SeleniumServer seleniumServer;

 public void setUp() throws Exception {

  RemoteControlConfiguration rc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
  rc.setSingleWindow(true);
  seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer(rc);
  selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox",
    "https://mywebsite.com/");
  seleniumServer.start();
  selenium.start();
 }

 public void testLogin() {
  selenium.open("/");
  selenium.type("id=user_name", "test");
  selenium.type("id=password", "test");
  selenium.click("css=input.btn");
  selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
  assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Signed in successfully"));
 }

 public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException {
  selenium.stop();
  seleniumServer.stop();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main objective behind this question was to Run Selenium test in Firefox in a windows environment. I had a work around for this. I opened up an Internet Explore and went to Internet Options and went to connections and set the automatic .pac configuration there. Bingo! it worked.